# function not returning results when called from html file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that returns data based on the option (player) selected in the drop down. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52981008/how-to-create-a-dropdown-prompt-in-google-app-script) got me 90% of the way there, but I'm tripping over the last piece.

When I select any of my players from the drop down, I expect the sidebar to be populated with that player's stats, but it seems it returns nothing.

I have an onchange event that runs the function selectChange(this), which passes the name of the player I've selected to the function selectChange().

The selectChange() function runs function stats(), which returns the stats of the player for whom the function was passed

I assign what function stats() returns to a variable ("stats") and I overwrite my HTML element with the id "data" with those contents.

I know the stats() function is good - when I run function stats() independently and pass it a player (i.e. stats('David Justice')), I get an expected return. So it's something to do with how I'm calling it in my html file, or how I'm passing the select.value component. I tried String(select.value) but that didn't seem to help. I suspect my error is trivial, but I can't find it!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1M4g.png)
[testStats function returns data as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytFc4.png)

Comment: Are you sure that when selectChange(this) is called, select.value returns the name of the player? What does it show in your console when the first/only thing  you do in selectChange(select) is console.log(select.value). Does it return the name?

Comment: Yes, I get back the name of the player

Comment: From the pictures the variables stats and data seems to be assigned the right way at first glance. But I can't check it because the code is an image and not a snippet.  So that leaves three things I can think of that might be causing your problems. 1. Try `data.innerHTML = stats;`  2. Make sure you place your semicolons, `;`, after your alert and the last line of the function. 3. Try to not name the functions and variables exactly the same.